# Can I use asyncio to read from and write to a multiprocessing.Pipe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe, python-asyncio

I need to communicate between processes in Python and am using `asyncio` in each of the processes for concurrent network IO.

Currently I'm using `multiprocessing.Pipe` to `send` and `recv` significantly large amounts of data between the processes, however I do so outside of `asyncio` and I believe I'm spending a lot of cpu time in `IO_WAIT` because of it.

It seems like `asyncio` can and should be used to handle the Pipe IO between processes, however I can't find an example for anything but piping STDIN/STDOUT.

From what I read it seems like I should register the pipe with `loop.connect_read_pipe(PROTOCOL_FACTORY, PIPE)` and likewise for write. However I don't understand the purpose of `protocol_factory` as it would relate to a `multiprocessing.Pipe`. It's not even clear if I should be creating a `multiprocessing.Pipe` or whether I can create a pipe within `asyncio`.

Comment: Just looking at the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#id12

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce something akin to the asyncio UDP echo server in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-client-protocol), a simple ping back and forth between processes, over pipes rather than over the network stack. An explanation of how to architect that same example over pipes would be a very helpful answer.

Comment: How about https://github.com/kchmck/aiopipe

Comment: @kmaork that looks like a good answer, if you post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`aiopipe`](https://github.com/kchmck/aiopipe) seems to do what you want! It can be used with the builtin `multiprocessing` module, and provides a similar API to the regular blocking pipes.

Answer (score 12):

`multiprocessing.Pipe` uses the high level `multiprocessing.Connection` module that pickles and unpickles Python objects and transmits additional bytes under the hood. If you wanted to read data from one of these pipes using `loop.connect_read_pipe()`, you would have to re-implement all of this yourself.

The easiest way to read from a `multiprocessing.Pipe` without blocking the event loop would be to use `loop.add_reader()`. Consider the following example:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing


def main():
    read, write = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    writer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(write,))
    writer_process.start()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(reader(read))


async def reader(read):
    data_available = asyncio.Event()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().add_reader(read.fileno(), data_available.set)

    while not read.poll():
        await data_available.wait()
        data_available.clear()

    print(read.recv())


def writer(write):
    write.send('Hello World')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pipes created using the lower-level `os.pipe` don't add anything extra the way that pipes from `multiprocessing.Pipe` do. As a result, we can use `os.pipe` with `loop.connect_read_pipe()`, without re-implementing any sort of inner-workings. Here is an example:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import os


def main():
    read, write = os.pipe()
    writer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(write,))
    writer_process.start()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(reader(read))


async def reader(read):
    pipe = os.fdopen(read, mode='r')

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    stream_reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
    def protocol_factory():
        return asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(stream_reader)

    transport, _ = await loop.connect_read_pipe(protocol_factory, pipe)
    print(await stream_reader.readline())
    transport.close()


def writer(write):
    os.write(write, b'Hello World\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[This code](https://github.com/bslatkin/pycon2014/blob/master/lib/asyncio-0.4.1/examples/child_process.py) helped me figure out how to use `loop.connect_read_pipe`.

Comment: doesn't the first code block break if there are multiple sends before a recv? or does the .poll() guard against that?

Comment: The .poll() guards against that. If there were earlier sends, the code will keep going to the .recv() call until all data in the pipe has been consumed.

Comment: Note that the `add_reader` strategy only works on Linux, and not on Windows