# What is the best way to wait for a synchronous condition with python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a syncronous condition which I need to wait for.
Currently I do active waiting like this:

```py
while my_syncronous_condition_is_not_fulfilled():
    asyncio.sleep(0.001)
```

This works, but I'm sure it is not very performant since with every call of `asyncio.sleep` there is an overhead. And choosing a bigger value like `asyncio.sleep(1)` is also not a good option because we do not want to wait longer than necessary.
What is the best way to do this?

Full code:

```py
async def calculate_in_subprocess(func, *args, **kwargs):
    rx, tx = Pipe(duplex=False)  # receiver & transmitter ; Pipe is one-way only
    process = Process(target=_inner, args=(tx, func, *args), kwargs=kwargs)
    process.start()

    while not rx.poll():  # do not use process.is_alive() as condition here
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

    result = rx.recv()
    process.join()  # this blocks synchronously! make sure that process is terminated before you call join()
    rx.close()

    if isinstance(result, Exception):
        raise result

    return result


def _inner(tx, fun, *a, **kw_args) -> None:
    """ This runs in another process. """

    event_loop = None
    if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(fun):
        event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)

    try:
        if event_loop is not None:
            res = event_loop.run_until_complete(fun(*a, **kw_args))
        else:
            res = fun(*a, **kw_args)
    except Exception as ex:
        tx.send(ex)
    else:
        tx.send(res)
```

Example usage:

```py
import time
import asyncio

def f(value: int) -> int:
     time.sleep(10)  # a long taking synchronous blocking calculation
     return 2 * value

asyncio.run(calculate_in_subprocess(func=f, value=42))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a better solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62098165/10975692

Inspired by this I ended up with:

```py
async def calculate_in_subprocess(func, *args, **kwargs):
    rx, tx = Pipe(duplex=False)  # receiver & transmitter ; Pipe is one-way only
    process = Process(target=_inner, args=(tx, func, *args), kwargs=kwargs)
    process.start()

    event = asyncio.Event()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_reader(fd=rx.fileno(), callback=event.set)

    if not rx.poll():
        await event.wait()

    loop.remove_reader(fd=rx.fileno())
    event.clear()

    result = rx.recv()
    process.join()  # this blocks synchronously! make sure that process is terminated before you call join()
    rx.close()

    if isinstance(result, Exception):
        raise result

    return result
```

This is much cleaner and has less overhead.